# VBA how to loop trough cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sharepoint-list

I have the following script, which is suppose to take data from my excel doc and upload the data into sharepoint list.

```
Sub AddItem()
'
' Requires a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.0 Libray" to insert a record into a sharepoint list "AccessLog"
'
    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mySQL As String

    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [Test];"

    With cnt ' See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/

.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://share.amazon.com/sites/IPV;List={2B0ED605-AE50-4D39-A46E-77CC15D6F17E};"
        .Open
    End With

    rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    rst.AddNew
        rst.Fields("Title") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value
        rst.Fields("Names") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").Value
    rst.Update ' commit changes to SP list

    If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
    If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
End Sub
```

The script works as intended, but the only "problem" is that with this method, I can only enter one element per field type.
I wanted to know if there was a way to loop trough all of the columns, so for example, rst.Fields("Title") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value then C4,C5 until the last row.

I would have the excel table like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope help you

```
Sub MySub()

    'In CurrRow you will save the row, before move between columns
    Dim CurrRow As Double
    Range("A1").Select ' Choice where it will start    first row and column
   
    Do While ActiveCell <> "" 'loop row
    
        CurrRow = ActiveCell.Row ' save current row
    
        Do While ActiveCell <> "" 'loop column
       
            '----
        
        
            'Your code operations or anything you need to do with each cell
        
        
            '----
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select ' next column
        Loop
        Range("A" & CurrRow).Select '<--Change A if need, equal as the first column
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select ' next row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Cells(row,col) to access the cell values instead of named ranges.

```
for row = 1 to max_row
    recordset.addnew
    for col = 1 to max_col
        recordset.fields(col).value = worksheet.cells(row, col).value
    next col
    recordset.update
next row
```